# How validate forms without js jq

Tags: php, forms, validation

Hello i do have a problem,i do not use js or jq just bootstrap link in head,it shoud pop up if forms are invalid but for some reason it wont,thats my prob.On some my other codes it is working but now it wont here i dont know why,i wouldnt post this,but struggling with trivials like this for a day :( dont give me minuses,i dont ask for plus but neither - I would appreciate hlp!

```
  *Signup back*
  <?php 
   if(isset($_POST['signup-submit'])){
    require 'db.inc.php';
    $error = false; 

    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pwdrpt = $_POST['pwd_repeat'];
    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdrpt)) {
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
      }   
    // else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)){
    //     header("location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid");
    //     exit();
     // }
    elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error = true;
          $errorEmail = 'Please input a valid Email address';
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
        exit();
      } 
    elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)){
        $error = true;
        $errorUsername = 'Please input username';
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
        exit();
      } 



       *SignUp front*
       <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post" novalidate>
      <h3  align="center"><strong>Sign Up<strong></h3> 

      <!-- <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
          if ($_GET['error'] == 'invalidmail') {
            echo '<p class="signuperror">Enter valid email address!</p>';
          }
        }
      ?> -->

      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uid">
      <div><span class="text-danger"><?php if(isset($errorUsername)) echo $errorUsername; ?></span> 
        </div>
        <br>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="mail"> 
      <div><span class="text-danger"><?php if(isset($errorEmail)) echo $errorEmail; ?></span></div>
```

Comment: remove exit() from your code

Comment: tried ,not helped

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Just in url from code,but on screen not.

Comment: remove <!-- html comments --> from message printing section

Comment: <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
          if ($_GET['error'] == 'invalidmail') {
            echo '<p class="signuperror">Enter valid email address!</p>';
          }
        }
      ?> like this

Comment: Neither,i must skipped something no fck way nothing workds :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['signup-submit'])){
$error = false; 

$username = $_POST['uid'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];

if (empty($username) || empty($email)) {
    header("location: index1.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();
  }   
elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error = true;
      $errorEmail = 'Please input a valid Email address';
    header("location: index1.php?error=invalidmail");
    exit();
  } 
elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)){
    $error = true;
    $errorUsername = 'Please input username';
    header("location: index1.php?error=invaliduid");
    exit();
  } 
}


   ?>
   <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
  <h3  align="center"><strong>Sign Up<strong></h3> 

  <?php 
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
      if ($_GET['error'] == 'invalidmail') {
        echo '<p class="signuperror">Enter valid email address!</p>';
      }
    }
  ?> 

  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uid">
  <div><span class="text-danger"><?php if(isset($errorUsername)) echo $errorUsername; ?></span> 
    </div>
    <br>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="mail"> 
  <div><span class="text-danger"><?php if(isset($errorEmail)) echo $errorEmail; ?></span></div>   
  <input type="submit" name="signup-submit" id="signup-submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Thx Rathod it is working,still i dont know where i made mistake :)))

Comment: I think you forget to close if(isset($_POST['signup-submit'])){ this bracets :)